# how to get image whose path is stored in database in Gridview of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, image, gridview

Hi i have stored the images in mysql using the varchar datatype and i am storing the path of that and i want to retrive that images in the gridview of asp.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ImageField, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" 
  DataSource='<%# GetData() %>' AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PictureURL"></asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```